# Why my jQuery ajax call is not successful

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am developing my web app and run it on localhost:8080, in my js file, I have an ajax call to get xml data from server:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://COMPANY_DOMAIN.com/company-interface/the-id',
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'application/xml',
        data: {id: 43},
        success: function(data) {

            alert(data);

        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error){
            alert('error happens');
        }
     })
```

I can access the url **http://COMPANY_DOMAIN.com/company-interface/the-id/?id=43** which will show the xml result on browswer, but my above ajax call always go to error function.

I checked in firebug, the 'xml' tab shows "**XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{9fd0dca8-cf07-4401-b1de-ab04e8aa00bc} Line Number 1, Column 1**:" and firebug shows the URL GET is **http://COMPANY_DOMAIN.com/company-interface/the-id/?id=43& =1302610001570**.

Why firebug GET shows the "**...& =1302610001570**"? what does it means? why my ajax call is failed, though I can access that URL?

----------------EDIT---------------

Hi, I changed to use **localhost** request like:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/company-interface/the-id',
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            dataType: 'xml',
            data: {id: 43},
            success: function(data) {

                alert(data);

            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error){
                alert('error happens');
            }
         })
```

But I got the same error... more suggestions please... thank you.

Comment: The extra parameter prevents caching of the queried page. If this is not working it's probably due to cross domain security issues

Answer (score 3):

This is possibly due to **cross domain access control**. You are accessing the site which is on your machine which tries to connect to another website. This is not allowed unless you define `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers.

Also as @Craig said, content type as `xml` is needs to be changed.

Comment: How to define Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers?? I am developing a pure javascript project, with one index.html file as the start point. In which file and how to define the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header??

Comment: This needs to be set by your server. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: Also search SO for Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is subject to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Your script running on localhost can't access COMPANY_DOMAIN.com.

Answer (score 1):

Try Below code :

```
 $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/company-interface/the-id',
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            dataType: 'text',
            data: {id: 43},
            success: function(data) {

            // Assume response like..
            // <note>
            //    <from>Jani</from>
            //    <to>Tove</to>
            //    <message>Remember me this weekend</message>
            //  </note>

            xmlDoc = $.parseXML( data ),
            $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
            $message = $xml.find("message")
            alert($message.text());
            $("#xmlResonse").html($message.text());

        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error){
            alert('error happens');
        }
     })
```

Answer (score 0):

change your datatype to `application/xml` or `text/xml`

As the other comment suggests, is your URL on another domain? If not then try using relative URL's instead.

Comment: I changed, but it does not change anything...:(

Answer (score 0):

1302610001570 is for measuring response,

did you checked if the response create valid xml?

Comment: No, as I mentioned, there is an XML Parsing Error message

Comment: What do you mean about meauring response? Where can I get it?

Comment: I mean this is used for you to see how long the request changed from sending the request to get data